# Indian Female doctor in Saudi Arabia seeking UK general Visit Visa

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications

I'm an Indian Female doctor working in Saudi Arabia and planning to travel to the UK for my PACES examination. I would like to know the list of documents needed to make a general Visit Visa application in Saudi Arabia Riyadh.

Comment: Hello. Wouldn’t that list be available on the visa application centre website?

Comment: A Guide to Supporting Documents for Visitor visas is available on Gov.uk https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

Comment: @Traveller possibly expand into an answer?

Comment: @Mark Mayo I originally posted the comment as an answer but it received a downvote, possibly because I didn’t list out all the potential documents an applicant could provide. I didn’t do that because a) the OP appeared to have done no research prior to posting their question and in fact could have found the Guide themselves very easily via a Google search; b) it’s pointless copying out chunks of the Guide when the OP can read it for themselves via the link.

Comment: @Traveller not totally pointless, sometimes (often) the link changes/breaks and the info is gone